# kubernetes - nginx ingress - How to access

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I could not access my application from the k8s cluster.
With nodePort everything works. If I use ingress controller, I could see that it is created successfully. I am able to ping IP. If I try to telnet, it says connection refused. I am also unable to access the application. What do i miss? I do not see any exception in the ingress pod.

```
kubectl get ing -n test   
                 
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
web-ingress   <none>   *       192.168.0.102   80      44m


ping 192.168.0.102

PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.795 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.860 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.631 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.102 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2038ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.631/0.762/0.860/0.096 ms

telnet 192.168.0.102 80

Trying 192.168.0.102...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

---

```
kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
```

shows this

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-htvkh        0/1     Completed   0          99m
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-cf8gj         0/1     Completed   0          99m
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-7fd7d8df56-kll4v   1/1     Running     0          99m

NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.102.220.87    <none>        80:31692/TCP,443:32736/TCP   99m
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.106.159.230   <none>        443/TCP                      99m

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           99m

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-7fd7d8df56   1         1         1       99m

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           7s         99m
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           8s         99m
```

Comment: You need a Service defined which will routes traffic to your Ingress Controller - `kubectl get services`. Do you have an Ingress Controller up - `kubectl get pods`. Ingress alone will do nothing if Ingress Controller not running. Please do `kubectl get all` in the relevant namespaces

Comment: @Serge ,Do i need the ingress controller in my 'test' namespace? the nginx controller is running in its own namespace.

Comment: From memory `nginx-ingress` defaults to cluster-scope (all namespaces). But you would have to check how you deployed it

Comment: @Serge , updated the question with more info

Comment: You don't have a service with an external IP - are you within the same network as your cluster? If not, you won't be able to hit the `ingress-nginx-controller ` ClusterIP. Or try `kubectl get pods -o wide` and find which node the ingress controller is on, use its IP with `curl <ip>:80`

Comment: I see. Makes sense. How to add external ip. You have any idea?

Comment: If this is a managed cluster (GKE/Azure/AWS), I would suggest you create a service of type LoadBalancer and use that external IP. Otherwise you may be stuck with NodePort on this cluster and you need to monitor which node the ingress controller pod is on and use the node ip. I can make an answer with these details if you think that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The IP from `kubectl get ing -n test` is not an externally accessible address that you should be using.

Your NGINX Ingress Controller Deployment has a Service deployed alongside it. You can use the external IP of this Service (if it has one) to hit your Ingress Controller.

Because your Service is of NodePort type (and does not show an external IP), you must address the Ingress Controller Pods through your cluster's Node IPs. You would need to track which Node the Pod is on, then find the Node's IP. Here is an example of doing this:

```
NODE=$(kubectl get pods -o wide | grep "ingress-nginx-controller" | awk {'print $8'})
NODE_IP=$(kubectl get nodes "$NODE" -o wide | grep Ready | awk {'print $7'})
```

### More Info

If your cluster is managed (i.e. GKE/Azure/AWS), you can use a LoadBalancer Service to provide an external IP to hit the Ingress Controller.